# Computing a base of kernel and image of a linear map given the associated matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm trying to compute a base of the following linear map:
$$T : \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$$ with the following matrix associated with the map:
$$M = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
2 & 2 & 4 \\
3 & 2 & 5
\end{bmatrix}$$

I know how to calculate the base of its kernel but I'm unsure about the reasoning I followed to find a base of its image. This is what I did for the kernel:
$$\text{Ker} \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
2 & 2 & 4 \\
3 & 2 & 5
\end{bmatrix} = \text{Ker} \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 2 & 2 \\
0 & 2 & 2
\end{bmatrix} = \text{Ker} \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 2 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
-t \\
-t\\
t
\end{bmatrix} $$

My understanding is that the image of this map is the span of the columns of its associated matrix. With the above Gauss elimination steps, we found that the first two vectors making it up are linearly independent, whereas the second one is dependent on them.

Therefore, a base of $\text{Im } T$ is $\text{Span}\left(\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
2\\
3\\
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
2\\
2
\end{bmatrix}\right)$.
The sizes of the two subspaces add up to $3$, which is a hint I might be correct.
Is my reasoning sound or did I get something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is correct. One little remark concerning the notation: The kernel is a set, therefore, you should write e.g.

$$\operatorname{Ker}(M) = \left \{ \begin{pmatrix} -t \\ -t \\ t \end{pmatrix} : t \in \mathbb{R} \right \}.$$